# Show two RCPCs are regularly homotopic

Tags: differential-geometry, homotopy-theory

Show that the following regular parametrised closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$, defined
on the interval $[0, 1]$, are regularly homotopic.

Construct a regular homotopy between
them and verify that it satisfies the definition of regular homotopy.

$γ_1(t) = (cos(2πt),sin(2πt), 0)$ and $γ_2(t) = (cos(2πt),sin(2πt),sin(2πlt))$

where $l$ is a non-zero integer.

This is the first time I've ever done questions about regular homotopy, and all the theorems I have like Whitney-Graustein are for $\mathbb{R}^2$ so don't know how to even begin for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I know the definition of a regular homotopy, I just need some help on how to go about the proof.

Comment: Consider $H(s,t) = (1-s)\gamma_1(t) + s\gamma_2(t)$.

Comment: @DIdier_ what is H(s,t)?

Comment: Show it is a regular homotopy (hence, the "$H$") between your two curves.

Comment: @DIdier_ Is this a general formula or specific to just this example?

Comment: It is a usual construction for these examples. Sometimes, topological obstructions force us to use more advanced constructions.